# ggplot: boxplot with 95% confidence interval

Tags: matplotlib, ggplot2, statistics, boxplot, confidence-interval

I'd like to plot a boxplot with 95% confidence interval error bars. I'm getting very confused.

What are the statistical properties of the default error bars? Are those 95 intervals? (I think the answer is no.) Is there a simple way to achieve this? It seems like a common metric to plot.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `geom_boxplot(notch = TRUE)`, the notches will give you a roughly 95% interval around the median. 
See : https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_boxplot.html

If it's the mean you're after, I'd superpose `geom_jitter() + geom_errorbar()` but calculations are not automated anymore.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like it for the mean, not the median. I believe the correct answer is to use a point plot instead of a boxplot.